# 3D application of basic trigonometry

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsHux.jpg (can't be uploaded because of size)

I first thought that ON//BC, because B is due east of O and C is due north of B.

However, that results in me getting an incorrect value of OT(correct value = 39.3)

Answer (score 1):

Let $OB=a$.

Thus, $$OT=a\tan40^{\circ}$$ and
$$OC\tan25^{\circ}=a\tan40^{\circ},$$
which gives
$$OC=\frac{a\tan40^{\circ}}{\tan25^{\circ}}$$ and by Pythagoras theorem we obtain:
$$70^2+a^2=\left(\frac{a\tan40^{\circ}}{\tan25^{\circ}}\right)^2$$ and from here we can find a value of $a$:
$$a=\frac{70}{\sqrt{\frac{\tan^240^{\circ}}{\tan^225^{\circ}}-1}}$$ and $OT$.

I got $OT=39.262...$

Comment: Oh gosh, I would never have thought of that. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Ong Hai Xiang You are welcome!